# Push data server to client web app, how to?

Tags: asp.net, signalr, push, real-time

(Regarding Web apps, asp.net 5)

I'm new to this stuff, i want to push data from the server to the client. Displaying 'real-time' data on a website. (something like a chat window).

How should i realize this? I've read about SingalR, but most information seems to be outdated? Is this still a good choice?

For example, one of the problems i run into is when i try to add this:
app.MapSignalR();
to my startup.cs

Error   CS1061  'IApplicationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'MapSignalR' and no extension method 'MapSignalR' accepting a first argument of type 'IApplicationBuilder' could be found

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Did you install `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR` package from NuGet? This tutorial: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc shows how to write simple chat. It's quite old (1.5 year), but I believe it's still accurate. I used SignalR in some of my projects and it work just fine...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did try that tutorial, but i dont have this 'IAppBuilder' in Asp.Net 5, i have IApplicationBuilder. therefore app.MapSignalR(); won't work, and i dont know how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do this with [a bridge between `IAppBuilder` and `IApplicationBuilder`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2014/11/14/katana-asp-net-5-and-bridging-the-gap/) as shown [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/blob/dev/samples/Owin.IAppBuilderBridge/KAppBuilderExtensions.cs):

```
public static IApplicationBuilder UseAppBuilder(this IApplicationBuilder app, Action<IAppBuilder> configure)
{
    app.UseOwin(addToPipeline =>
    {
        addToPipeline(next =>
        {
            var appBuilder = new AppBuilder();
            appBuilder.Properties["builder.DefaultApp"] = next;

            configure(appBuilder);

            return appBuilder.Build<AppFunc>();
        });
    });
    return app;
}
```

Which you would then [call from startup](https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/blob/dev/samples/Owin.IAppBuilderBridge/Startup.cs) to start SignalR:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseAppBuilder(appBuilder =>
    {
        appBuilder.MapSignalR();

        appBuilder.Run(context =>
        {

        });
    });
}
```

Some context, excerpted from the link above:

> [In ASP.NET 5, now ASP.NET Core 1.0] the Startup class conventions
>   have been refined. Katana [the previous version] would search for an
>   assembly that specified the `OwinStartup` attribute and then fallback
>   to searching all assemblies for a class named Startup or
>   AssemblyName.Startup. ASP.NET does not define an attribute and it only
>   searches the primary application assembly for a type named Startup (in
>   any namespace). The `Configuration(IAppBuilder app)` method is now
>   `Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)`...
>
> Middleware that can’t remove their `IAppBuilder` or OwinMiddleware
>   dependencies can use a modified approach to run in ASP.NET 5. See this
>   linked sample for an IApplicationBuilder extension that provides an
>   IAppBuilder for use with Katana v3 based middleware. This extension
>   creates a new AppBuilder instance and then wraps the OWIN pipeline
>   builder pattern around it to integrate into ASP.NET 5.